# Unreal Engine 5 - Empty pointer in timer handler function

Tags: unreal-engine5

I create Actor called AMachine in editor of Unreal Engine 5. The actor has property which is pointer.

> UPROPERTY() UNiagaraSystem* PaylineSystem;

Then I assign NiagaraSystem to property PaylineSystem in Editor.
When I call timer by this code

> GetWorldTimerManager().SetTimer(MyTimerHandle, this,
> &AMachine::SetNextMatchState, 1.0f, true, 0.0f);

property PaylineSystem is empty in method SetNextMatchState.
What cause that my property is empty and how I can prevent it ?
I tried many types of pointers, but allways with the same result.